# Subversion version of GitHub?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, github

I'd like to host some open source code on a public repository, and I really like how pretty GitHub makes this kind of sharing.

Unfortunately, Git is not an option for these projects, for the most part because I'm developing for/on Windows, and Git support on Windows is not anywhere near where Subversion's support is.

I'd like to have something exactly like GitHub, but one where I could use Subversion instead. Does such a service exist?

Comment: Have you tried TortoiseGit? It works quite nicely.

Comment: I'm not  a great git fan, but Windows support has improved lately. Have you tried the latest version from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit.

Comment: It doesn't integrate with Visual Studio, however. Visual SVN seems to be the only tool that consistently doesn't screw up my projects and automaticly leaves out things that shouldn't be in the repo.

Comment: What is the proiblem with Git on Windows? I use it on Windows and it works great for me.

Comment: there are also other DVCS, for instance mercurial + tortoisehg and visualhg

Comment: Laykes: Sure, if you don't want to support Unicode paths. MinGW doesn't support unicode, and therefore msysgit doesn't either.

Comment: @jk: Still don't integrate with Visual Studio.

Comment: Can't you just open a project on code.google.com and use svn as version control? Not as nice a website but the same principle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) offers SVN as one of many features, and is free for Open Source projects, as does [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/)

Comment: Hmm... I can't believe I didn't think of that one!

Answer (score 11):

> I'd like to have something exactly like GitHub, but one where I could use Subversion instead. Does such a service exist?

No, it doesn't exist.

And it *cannot* exist. The features of GitHub are highly dependent on distributed version control. In fact, the majority of all the features that make "sharing pretty" have absolutely nothing to do with GitHub, they are fundamental features of distributed version control.

So, you can have something exactly like [GitHub](https://GitHub.Com/) (or [Gitorious](https://Gitorious.Org/), [codaset](https://Codaset.Com/)) for [Mercurial](http://Mercurial.Selenic.Com/) ([BitBucket](https://BitBucket.Org/)), [darcs](http://Darcs.Net/) ([Patch-Tag](https://Patch-Tag.Com/)), [Bazaar](http://Bazaar.Canonical.Com/) ([Launchpad](https://Launchpad.Net/)), Codeville, [Arch](http://GNU.Org/software/gnu-arch/), [ArX](http://WWW.NonGNU.Org/arx/), [Monotone](http://Monotone.Ca/), [Fossil](http://Fossil-SCM.Org/), but not for [Subversion](http://Subversion.Apache.Org/) (or [CVS](http://WWW.NonGNU.Org/cvs/), [Perforce](http://Perforce.Com/), [Visual SourceSafe](http://MSDN.Microsoft.Com/library/ms181038(VS.80).aspx), [Team Foundation Server](http://MSDN.Microsoft.Com/teamsystem/), [Vault](http://SourceGear.Com/vault/)), because centralized version control systems simply are not capable of supporting the required features.

Comment: When I say "pretty" I am being literal. Particularly things like showing diffs for commits, showing graphs for stats on what kind of code is in the repo, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at **Patch-Tag** for `darcs`! One more: I've also come across http://darcsden.com/ .

Comment: As for Git hosting, I'd like to add http://repo.or.cz . (I believe it's nice to know and use several hosting sites for your DVCS projects, so that they are independent public mirrors. That's why I want to list more known alternatives.)

Answer (score 8):

I use [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/) with Subversion.  I think it's a bit more involved than GitHub, but it provides free hosting for Open Source projects.

Comment: +1. Doesn't get the checkmark because they don't support the Boost Software License, but it looks really nice nontheless.

Answer (score 6):

http://unfuddle.com/ is one SVN host I have no complaints about at all.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this site](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/) for a comparison os SVN hosting services.

Answer (score 2):

You can check services such as [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://beanstalkapp.com/ and found it to be good for hosting projects. You should definitely give them a look if you really have to stick with SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Nice list of Subversion Hosting Comparison

http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com

Answer (score 1):

My company, [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com), does offer Subversion hosting, Git hosting, and Trac hosting for teams like yours.  For private code hosting, either we or our competitors mentioned above are a good fit.