# Pros and cons using Mercurial over Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

I'm starting a new project. I familiar with TortoiseSVN, and all its downsides. Shall I start using Mercurial instead? What are the pros and cons using Mercurial over Subversion?

Comment: Comparison here:
http://animeshdas.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/head-to-head-comparison-between-subversion-git-and-mercurial/ ...Although it's clear that this author has a soft spot for Mercurial.

Comment: First, you might want to familiarize yourself with the differences in the designs and goals of CVCS (SVN, CVS, etc) versus DVCS (Mercurial, Git, etc).

Comment: @Santa how? do you have any recommend book/link?

Comment: I don't know any book, myself. When I dived into the DVCS world  (first, git; then, mercurial), I just read tonnes of links and articles about them. First, I learned how to do basic versioning using their respective starter documentations, then I read about what they do behind the scenes. [Chapter 4](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html) of the hgbook is a great read, or [this](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/) for git. Once you grok DVCS, it will be easier to delve into the more advanced features, and appreciate its edge over CVCS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218471/for-home-projects-can-mercurial-or-git-or-other-dvcs-provide-more-advantages-o/1218657#1218657

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I enjoyed reading [Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com). It has a chapter called [Subversion Re-education](http://hginit.com/00.html) which might be worth a read in your situation.

Also there is a Mercurial client called [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) which is similar to TortoiseSVN. You might want to check out [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) also. I have used it in a couple of school projects and it's pretty cheap and even with the free plan you get one private repository.

The content of [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) is available online, for free.

Comment: Bitbucket now gives you unlimited private repositories for the free plan which is a huge plus in my book.

Answer (score 2):

A big benefit of Mercurial (and distributed systems generally) is that you do not need to be online to do your work. Your repositories are local, and your working copies are complete copies, with all the history, so no need for going back and forth like Subversion does.

Branching and merging tends to be easier, as well as receiving changes that others have made to their checkouts.