# Do any hardware (ASIC) companies use mercurial (hg)

Tags: svn, mercurial, hardware, cvs, asic

Do you know of any large companies (preferably hardware) successfully using mercurial as their version control system (vcs.)

I have experience with svn/cvs/perforce and a little git.
Internal politics is pushing us toward cvs, although I feel this is a poor choice:

Reasons I like perforce best:

1. battle tested in h/w companies.
2. handles large binaries well.
3. handles large projects very well > 10G.
4. handles symbolic links very sensibly.
5. provides atomic checkins.
6. flexible branching mechanism.
7. merge tools seem to work well.
8. user never needs to use admin commands.

Reasons I don't like CVS:

1. doesn't support atomic checkins.
2. database can get mangled.
3. may require admin commands to fix user error.

Reasons I like CVS:

1. battle tested.
2. most people are at least a little familiar with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. CVS is a bad choice. Lack of atomic check is enough to disqualify it in my book. People like it because they know it and they don't understand what's wrong with it.

The only difference between use of a system for hardware firms and software firms tends to be RTL modules have very well defined interfaces and are normally owned by one person, so development is very segmented. This actually works quite well with a centralised system as the need for branching is reduced. Developers don't tread on each others toes as much.

I've seen one hardware firm try Mercurial, and it was a mess. It wasn't that it was the wrong tool, but that they had a CVS mindset and tried to make it work like CVS. I wrote a rather ranting account [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714074/tips-on-upgrading-cvs-to-git-hg/9981139#9981139).

Personally I think SVN is quite a good fit to hardware development, especially for people coming from CVS. It's ability to check out sub-trees can also be useful. That said, I'm currently working in a place that tries to have a "feature branch" work-flow with SVN, and the merging has numerous pitfalls. They're thinking about git/hg in the future. They are a small, progressive firm though.

The firm that moved from CVS to Mercurial landed up going to Perforce. For them it was all about the support contract and having someone to blame. For the users.... well.... I think it presents a really complex front to the user. The whole workspace concept is just overkill, and branch management was a pain. As a system, it's capable, but a lot of work to use.

If I was to deploy Mercurial in another hardware firm I'd make heavy use of [sub-repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository). I'd do this to get back the useful part of sub-tree check outs from subversion i.e. that an RTL module could be checked out and branched in isolation. It'd also give me the concept of an integration project which would be the project that I would pull all the sub-modules into. This then decouples RTL releases from RTL development to some degree, and facilitates different chips using the same modules. Also, by keeping modules separate, the history is kept isolated as well, making tracking change on modules easier. Finally, it avoids the "hundreds of developers accessing one central repo and getting into merge races" problem I described in my other answer.