# Converting gitweb query strings to cgit queries

Tags: git, language-agnostic, url-rewriting, gitweb, cgit

I'm trying to programmatically map gitweb-format query strings to cgit query strings to transition fully to cgit without breaking old gitweb-based urls pointing to my repositories which are scattered here and there around the web. I've seen some regex-based URL rewriting rules such as the following:

http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/cgit-upgrade-gitweb-retired

but I'm trying to actually understand the variables in the query string to make sure I get it right, and I'll be using a tiny CGI program rather than mod_rewrite or whatever do to the remapping. In particular, I don't understand the semantics of the `h`, `hb`, and `hp` hashes and how they map to cgit's `id` query variables for different types of queries.

Can anyone familiar with them fill me in or point me to a good resource?

Comment: This seems somewhat helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737306/how-to-diff-files-directly-from-the-linux-kernel-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically

- `id` comes from `hashb` if the gitweb url uses `hashb`, otherwise from `hash`.
- `id2` comes from hashpb`if the gitweb url uses`hashpb`, otherwise from`hashp`.
- the rest is pretty straightforward.

Here's the script I'm using now (no external commands invoked if your shell doesn't suck):

```
#!/bin/sh

q=$QUERY_STRING
repo=
action=
hash=
hashp=
file=

while test "$q" ; do
x=${q%%;*}
case "$x" in
p=*) repo=${x#p=} ;;
a=*commit*) action=commit ;;
a=*plain*) action=plain ;;
a=*summary*) action= ;;
a=*log*) action=log ;;
a=*) action=${x#a=} ;;
h=*) hash=${x#h=} ;;
hb=*) hashb=${x#hb=} ;;
hp=*) hashp=${x#hp=} ;;
hpb=*) hashpb=${x#hpb=} ;;
f=*) file=${x#f=} ;;
esac
t=${q#*;}
test "$t" = "$q" && break
q=$t
done

test "$hashb" && hash=$hashb
test "$hashpb" && hashp=$hashpb

loc=/cgit

if test "$repo" ; then
        loc=$loc/$repo
        if test "$action" ; then
                loc=$loc/$action
                if test "$file" ; then
                        loc=$loc/$file
                fi
        fi
        if test "$hash" ; then
                loc=$loc/\?id=$hash 
                if test "$hashp" ; then
                        loc=$loc\&id2=$hashp
                fi
        fi
fi

printf 'Status: 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: %s\n\n' "$loc"
```