# Linux kernel versions diff using Linux Kernel git repository

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I want to see the difference between two kernel versions(say 2.6.35.3 to 3.0). I have opened 2.6.35.3 kernel from the browser using  http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?h=v2.6.36-rc3 .

Can you please tell how to select another kernel version from this page (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?h=v2.6.36-rc3) to see the diff.

Comment: As I know, web-version of the git repo allows to see only commit's diff, that is diff between current state and previous one. For diff between arbitrary states, you need to clone git repo **locally** and use appropriate commands of the git client.

Comment: Clone repository and do just `git diff v2.6.36-rc3..v3.0`. By the way to compare stable releases you have to pull from another repository.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Using cgit at kernel.org we can see difference. This link is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737306/how-to-diff-files-directly-from-the-linux-kernel-git-repository/1737606#1737606