# Toolbar disappeared in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, toolbar

Visual Studio ate my toolbar, I opened a solution for a project I've been working on for a few months, and the toolbar has 135 buttons on it, and while it was loading, the whole toolbar flickered like it was trying to give me a seizure or something, and then it dissappeared. Now when I click Debug, it won't let me do it because all the resources are missing!?

I'm using:

Visual Studio 2010 C# Express
Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I have searched Google and found nothing related. I'm hoping that Visual Studio can also somehow make bowel movements so I can find those missing resources and put everything back together again, but I don't think that's a likely scenario...

Has anybody ever experienced this before, and if so, are there any updates/fixes for this?

Comment: This sounds as if you do not have a *version control system*? I hope you can recover your toolbar ... but honestly - don't ever risk the work *of months* and install a *version control system* asap

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Googling now ;)

Comment: Or just look on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859/what-is-the-difference-between-all-the-different-types-of-version-control

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting link, thanks. I'm checking a few of them out. First ones are Visual Source Safe and Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all - shame on you for not having a backup or better using source control. Who basically cares whetehr you lost the current work, if your last working state is an "undo checkout" away.
- Second, your toolbar is code. Look into the code behind file. Find out what is wrong there / missing there. Comment parts out until it works again, then slowly uncomment them until you find the wrong issue ;)

Comment: Ahhh, yummy answer. Thank you! Will accept once the 10min period is over. It doesn't let me accept straight away anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I also experiment these situation. And the problem is Visual Studio.

When you add controls (ex. button, drop down buttons), Visual Studio has make code (automatically).

> Add, Modify, Add, Remove, Add, Modify

Too many times work has going on, then Visual Studio has delete `AddRange(...)` function.

```
: toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(...);
```

If this code was deleted, it seems like `new toolStrip(just like you project)`

So, I say, `Create New Project` and add `toolStrip1`, some buttons and Now comparing your
project source code (in `design.cs` file).