# How do I share the same Visual Project with my team?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to share the same Visual Studio 2010 project with my team where my team can work on the same project at the same time, anywhere, anytime.
I know TFS can do it,but I don't want to use it because we can't afford the license fee,can you please suggest another way which is simpler....

Please do reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category of tool you're looking for is called, alternatively, "Version Control", "Version Management", or "Revision Control". This software forms a critical part of a larger discipline called "Software Configuration Management".

For us, we use the [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) system. It's got excellent Windows support (and integrates nicely with Visual Studio with [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). It's all free, of course.

Other popular systems include [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). There are many, many others.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion). This way you can save your code. It isn't dependent on Visual Studio easy to expand/change/etc. Also if two or more people are working on the same project then the program can merge the files or show the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read a little more about version control. I must suggest these great posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control

[What is the difference between all the different types of version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859/what-is-the-difference-between-all-the-different-types-of-version-control)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), it's a subversion client that allows you to do exactly what you want to.

> TortoiseSVN is a really easy to use
>   Revision control / version control /
>   source control software for Windows.
>   Since it's not an integration for a
>   specific IDE you can use it with
>   whatever development tools you like.
>   TortoiseSVN is free to use. You don't
>   need to get a loan or pay a full years
>   salary to use it.