# Multiple coders on the same source

Tags: php, git, svn, fossil

I'm having a problem with my coders, they seems to keep on overwriting each others work
from time to time because they keep on working on overlapping files.

I've looked it up and it seems that "Fossil" might be the solution for me (http://www.fossil-scm.org) but i wanted to know if any one has a better idea as I'm pretty new to it all.

Comment: google for `svn` or `git` or `hg`, these things are called software version control :)

Comment: SVN is fine for this ! have you tried ? www.tortoisesvn.net/

Comment: That, or a box of floppy disks on the project manager's desk, one per file :D

Comment: I'd go with svn or git, since they're both widely used. Out of the two, if you are always connected to the repo server, you might be best going with svn, since it is less complicated to use (imo). There are advantages to git, but the learning curve may put you off if you are new to version control.

Comment: @halfer: I teach git to complete noobs in one day to work with. After they work for about a week with it, it take another 1-2 hour Q&A session. But that's normally all needed to use it in production for the first year. And those noobs are new to version control, I mean new, they never heard of it. I'd say SVN is much more complicated because it's client/server only which is, well, complicated.

Comment: @hakre - that's good to hear. Just offering my own perspective - probably based on how submodules work, which (imo) is more awkward than it should be, and not as easy as svn's externals. Perhaps I need to attend your course `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source (Version) control is the way to go. There are many different options for this each having positives and negative. Perhaps a look at this question may help you: [What is the difference between all the different types of version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859/what-is-the-difference-between-all-the-different-types-of-version-control)

Comment: Thank you, 
it seems like i've a lot of reading to do..  i assume i'll indeed go with either GIT or SVN.

Comment: I've not tried fossil to comment on it I've used both svn and git to manage php code bases and I have been happy with both although now prefer git.