# Individual programmer interested in version control for the first time

Tags: version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Version Control.  Getting started…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658/version-control-getting-started)

I am interested in implementing version control for the first time. I am starting to amass custom libraries and would like to know what methods you would recommend for implementing version control on a Windows Vista OS. I also have an Ubuntu server setup. I'm not sure if OS is relevant.

<strike>Also, if it is relevant, I primarily use PHP and AS3.</strike>

Thanks!

Comment: This sort of thing has been covered on here before. I suggest looking through the [top-voted questions tagged `version-control`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=version-control&sort=votes&pagesize=50). Here are a few I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658/version-control-getting-started, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Answer (score 7):

Usually I recommend either [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/). If you use Windows, SVN may be a better option (I believe the GIT binaries are still in beta for Windows, and the SVN clients are better). I'd also recommend registering for a hosted version system (such as [github](http://github.com/) or [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)). Most services offer a free option, and will provide far better data replication than an any individual could create. Lastly, check out a GUI client (such as [Tortise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)) or check for integrations with the IDE you use for editing code.

Comment: Git is worth learning. Works great on Windows; has for a long time. No IDE integration required.

Comment: Good to know. I use GIT on my Mac also without any problems. IDE integration is a nice to have for beginners (and in general).

Comment: If you use SVN, definitely get the SVK toolkit to enhance it.  You get almost all the distributed functionality you get in git.  

As for the "far-better-data-replication" comment above, that's taking the github/beanstalk/gitorious folks at blind faith.

Comment: Very few developers will be able to implement the same data redundancy policies that these services offer (especially those just setting up version control for the first time). I know that git hub offers tri-server redundancy with offsite backups and beanstalk offers redundancy and offsite backups. Finally, you can keep your own copies if you are hyper-paranoid. It seems like your blind faith comment is a blind accusation...

Comment: From a client perspective, Git is perfectly useable and stable enough for production use on Windows - we've been using it for the last 6 months or so with no issues. For ease of use, combine it with a client like SmartGit or Git Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial at http://hginit.com/ covers a lot of ground regarding the concepts behind version control, specifically distributed version control. [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is the focus of the tutorial, but the concepts extend to [git](http://git-scm.com/) as well, and to other SCMs to a small degree.

My biggest recommendation is just to start using some version control, right now. It'll change the way you work--honestly.

(full disclosure: I work for Fog Creek, the sponsor of the hginit tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

Last question first: what language you're using doesn't really matter.  Even for text documents, Word documents, etc., a source control system will keep track of your versions.

As for which one to use, there are a number of free ones available, that require different levels of administration and expertise.  If you're mostly comfortable with Windows programs, SourceGear licenses their [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/index.html) product free for single users.

Open source repositories are also not uncommon.  [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) is widely used, but does require a fair amount of server administration expertise.

Comment: Unless you use something like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which can use a file-system-based repository.

Comment: One of the beautiful bits about Subversion is that you can set it up as a webdav interface, so it can double as sort of a Sharepoint-type clone for your desktop users, with almost no extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

For an individual, Bazaar in Solo mode is very easy to use.   Later if you want a multi-user configuration, other "workflows" are possible.

Comment: It looks like Bazaar is not developed now, which is pretty sad, the last news from the website are coming from 2016: https://launchpad.net/bzr

Answer (score 1):

Go with something like http://beanstalkapp.com

SVN is probably more conceptually easy to understand than Git, and it has more users - hence more tools and easier to find help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Subversion (SVN) using the Red Bean [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) as a guide. Start with Appendix A, then go through chapters 1, 2 at least.

This is my recommendation primarily because it is how I started with version control, not because I think SVN is better than other version control systems.

I agree with Kevin Gessner just start using something and feel the change wash over you!

Answer (score 0):

We use Mercurial. It is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Git, Mercurial, or Bazaar