# How can they develop 2 continuous version of google chrome at the same time?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I see some softwares are being developed more than one version at a time. Ex: Google chrome 15 is being developed when version 14 is still in Beta, Firefox 4 and 5 is being developed together. I wonder how could that be possible? What if there is a bug found in Chrome 14, does the team work on version 15 have to fix that bug again? Isn't working on just one version at a time would be more efficient and consistent?

Comment: See RichieHindle answer below. If you don't how they are doing this it probably means you aren't using Version Control. START TODAY! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658/version-control-getting-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a source code control system such as Subversion, Git, Mercurial, etc. you can manage multiple **branches** of your code, and merge edits from one branch to another quite easily.

Branches are often used to maintain a current **stable** version of a product, in which you fix bugs but don't add major features, and a **development** version to which you add new features.

During the development of the new features branch, you periodically **merge** the bugfixes from the stable branch into it.  The source control system automates that merge process to a large extent.